# spy/monitor and decode spi protocol between master and slave

Tags: spi, protocol

I often find my self in a situation when i need to debug systems of a MCU and other device which comunicate by SPI interface.

most of the times we use a logic analyzer between the master and the slave , which can decode to hex or binary , its very time comsuming.

is there a tool where i can define a custom protocol , so the frames are decoded and automaticaly?

Comment: Many logic analyzers have SPI decoding.  What are you using?

Comment: Single step the code with a debugger is the usual tool. Just staring at the raw data on a scope without access to the actual code at the same time isn't very productive.

Answer (score -1):

Sigrok is free/open source software able to operate most logic analyzers intended to support custom python backends and including many such example decoders.

You can also simple pipe output into a solution in some other language.

Comment: thats exactly what im trying to avoid. :)   Thanks for your answer ..

instead of coding a script , i would like a logic analizer that has built in decoding feature.... it would make me save some time , also it would be great to be able to trigger on some specific command or condition

Comment: You get what you ask for - you said "custom" which practically much means "script".  For basic things like I2C most analyzers already do that.